# Apache redirect:avoid redirect loop

Tags: apache, redirect

I am having trouble redirecting to a particular directory. Say, I type in www.example.com, I want to be directed to a particular directory like www.example.com/directory.

I added this to my virtual host in my apache config file

Redirect permanent / example.com/directory

but it goes into a redirect loop and the URL in the address bar appears like this

`http://example.com/directorydirectorydirectorydirectorydirectorydirectorydirectorydirectorydirectorydirectory`

How do I set up a redirect so that as soon as a person types in the URL example.com it takes them to example.com/directory?

Answer (score 2):

Replace your `Redirect` line with this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/$ /directory/
```

Comment: ...and do not forget to clear the browser's cache. Permanent redirects (code 301) really stay there :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) in order to do it.